# How to compare two lists of companies with name as a primary key for finding what's new, updated?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to modify the below code, comparing two lists of companies for finding:

1) Companies in Waltek that do not exist in valuetek, refereed as new companies in valuetek list.

2) companies in Waltek that needs updated (eg. some value attribute has changed)

```
 private void MergeCompanies()
    {
        // build a merged list of companies
        //find companies in Waltek that do not exist in Valuetek refered as new companies in Valuetek list.
        //find companies in Waltek that need updated (some value has changed)

        CombinedCompanies = new List<Company>();

        CombinedCompanies.AddRange(Companies);

        foreach (Company cmp in WaltekCompanies)
        {


            if (!Companies.Any(c => c.name.ToLower() == cmp.name.ToLower()))
            {

                //this must be a new company;
                CombinedCompanies.Add(cmp);

                //mark cmp as being NEW

            }
            else
            {
                //this company exists - have any values changed.
                //mark cmp as being upated or not

            }
        }


    }
```

Company Class:

```
 public class Company
{
    [NonSerialized]
    public bool isNew;

    public string project_id { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public bool account_company { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string duns_no { get; set; }
    public string ein_no { get; set; }
    public string telephone { get; set; }
    public string company_type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string fax { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string company_category { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }

    public Company() // constructor
    {
        address = new Address();
        isNew = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly, help me with this problem. Thank you!!

Comment: Sounds like you should be `Join`ing your two collections.

Answer (score 0):

You need a join. Something like:

```
var joined = from w in WaltekCompanies
             join c in Companies on c.name equals w.name into t
             from c in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { company = c, waltek = w };
```

Then to get the items in `WaltekCompanies` that aren't in `Companies`:

```
var newCompanies = joined.Where(j => j.company == null);
```

And to get updated companies you could do something like:

```
var updates = joined.Where(j => j.company != null && 
              SomeFunctionThatComparesCompanies(j.company, j.waltek))
```

Comment: I am facing an error for "c.name" & "w.name" where c,w are inaccessible due to its protection level. @Matt Burland

Comment: @Rev4: Well what does your `Company` class look like?

Comment: I have added the Company class to the code above. Please check for reference. Thank you. @Matt Burland